# Expand $\sin\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right)$ into powers of $z-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

**Problem:**

> Obtain the following Laurent expansions. State the first four nonzero terms. State explicitly the $n$th term in the series, and state the largest possible annular domain in which your series is a valid representation of the function.
>
> 3. $f(z) =\sin\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right)$ expanded in powers of $z-1$

**Attempt at solution:**

I had already solved everything (and checked my solutions with those in the back of the book) except the very last part concerning the annular domain. Now, I know that if the function is analytic in the annular domain $D = r_1 < |z-z_0| < r_2$, then the function can be represented by a Laurent series in powers of $z-z_0$.

Thus, for this particular case, my $z_0=1$. Now, I need to find where $f(z)$ is not analytic. I know that $\sin(z)$ is entire (analytic everywhere) and I know that $1+\frac{1}{z-1}$ is analytic everywhere except at the isolated singularity when $z=1$. Thus, by composing these functions, $f(z)$ is analytic everywhere except at $z=1$. Thus, it is analytic in the domain $0<|z-1|<\infty$. Thus, it seems I would be able to conclude that the Laurent expansion is valid in $0<|z-1|<\infty$, but according to my textbook, the solution is $|z-1|>1$. I've been thinking about this all day but I can't seem to convince myself of the solution in the textbook so any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Did for clarity, you could have started with the Taylor series for $\sin(1+z)$

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks for your comment. It seems wonderfully offtopic though.

Comment: @Did Yes, I apologize, I wrote this question when I was new to MSE and didn't know that the question asked could accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$f(z)=\sin(1)\cos\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)+\cos(1)\sin\left(\frac1{z-1}\right),$$
and recall the well-known expansions, valid for every $u$ in $\mathbb C$,
$$
\cos(u)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}(-1)^n\frac{u^{2n}}{(2n)!},
\qquad
\sin(u)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}(-1)^n\frac{u^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.
$$
Thus, on the annular $\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$,
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}a_n\cdot\left(\frac1{z-1}\right)^n,
\qquad 
a_n=\text{____}.
$$

Comment: Hmm...so do you think that the solution in the textbook is a typo in regards to the annular? 

Thanks for the possible method for the solution for $a_n$ although I had already found $a_n$ (using a slightly different tactic as well, but yours might give me some good insight on later problems).

Comment: Typo: obviously, yes. What did you find for $a_n$, and how?

Comment: I looked at the Taylor series expansion centered at 1 at $\sin(z)$ first. For $n$ even, I got $(-1)^\frac{n}{2}*\sin(1)/n!$ and for $n$ odd, I got $(-1)^\frac{n+1}{2}*\cos(1)/n!$. Thus, $\sin(w) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (w-1)^k*a_n$. Substituting, $w= 1+\frac{1}{z-1}$, I get $\sin(1+\frac{1}{z-1}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{z-1})^k*a_n$.

Comment: Seems pretty equivalent to what is suggested in the post.

Comment: I suppose so, although I think it was a good idea of you to split the function up into the two parts initially.